# How to fix a query that produces too many rows?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm designing Firebird 3.0 database for service sales, for example, for beauty saloons etc.

The database has the tables:

**Serv** - for service's list;

**ServRecs** - for service sales records;

**Docs** - for service documents;

**Calc** - for service calculations i.e. which raw material is used in specific service, quantity of raw material etc;

**RecsOut** - for raw material output records (sales);

**RecsIn** - for raw material Input records;

**Inventory** - for raw material's & good's names and properties.

---

**Serv**: Id, name, qnt, Vat...

**ServRecs**: Id, serv_id, Doc_id, qnt...

**Docs**: doc_id, docN, DocDT, Summ, ...

**Calc**: Id, serv_id, RawMat_id, qnt, unit_id...

**RecsOut**: id, doc_id, good_id, RecsIn_id

**RecsIn**: id, good_id...

**Inventory**: id, name (Rawaterial's and good's name)...

Let me explain with an **example**:
There is service document 323. There are 2 services used in it: service with serv_id=7 (hair cutting) and serv_id=8 (hair washing). As ServRecs table's qnt field shows service with serv_id=8 is used 2 times (i.e. 2 washing, before and after coloring), service with serv_id=7 only 1 time. As Calc table shows, generally, on service #7 are used raw material with id=11446 15ml and with id=11448 15ml, on service #8 - raw material with id=11450 10ml. That is, total used: raw material 11446 - 15ml, 11448 - 15ml and 11450 - 20ml (2*10ml).

[image]

My query looks like this:

```
select
i.id,
i.name as UsedRawMaterialName,
s.name as ServiceName,
ro.doc_id as ServiceDoc_id,
ri.cost as CostofRawMaterial,
sr.qnt as ServiceQnt,   --used service quantity, for example, 2 times washing 
sr.qnt*c.qnt as UsedRawMaterialQnt, --used service quantity*rawmaterial's used for 1 service
i.unit_k 

 from Inventory I, RecsOut ro, RecsIn ri,  calc c,  servrecs sr, serv s, Docs d, unit u,
  where
 d.doc_id= ro.doc_id and d.doc_id=sr.doc_id and d.doc_id=323  and
 s.id=c.serv_id and sr.serv_id=c.serv_id and
 c.rawmat_id=i.id and
 ro.recsIn_id=ri.id and
 i.unit_k=u.unit_k
```

My aim is get result like this:

[image]

However, the query returns result with redundant records and wrong values like this:

[image]

What is wrong in my query?

**Update 1:**
I changed "old-style Join syntax" with "new-style Join syntax" and easily find out that error was in "Join RecsOut ro on ro.id=i.id" clause. "New-style Join" is really very visually informative than old-style.

```
select
 i.id,
 i.name as UsedRawMaterialName,
 s.name as ServiceName,
 ro.doc_id as ServiceDoc_id,
 ri.cost as CostofRawMaterial,
 sr.qnt as ServiceQnt,   --used service quantity, for example, 2 times washing 
 sr.qnt*c.qnt as UsedRawMaterialQnt, --used service quantity*rawmaterial's used for 1 service
 i.unit_k 
        
 from  
 Inventory I Join RecsOut ro on ro.id=i.id
             Join RecsIn ri on ro.recsin_id=ri.id 
             Join calc c on c.rawmat_id=i.id
             join ServRecs sr on sr.serv_id=c.serv_id
             Join serv s on s.id=c.serv_id
             Join doc d on d.doc_id=ro.doc_id and 
                           d.doc_id=sr.doc_id and 
                           d.doc_id=323 
             join unit u on i.unit_k=u.unit_k
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @basti: the "new style" is over 30 years old.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including DDL of the tables and insert statements with example data, and expected results and actual results for that example data. Try to simplify the example as much as possible. Do not use screenshots, but use code blocks and markdown tables.

Comment: @basti A major benefit of the "New Style Join" is that each table can be brought in one at a time during development and testing.  With each table "joined" it is very straightforward to see which relationship has generated more (or indeed less) records than you are expecting

Comment: converting to "new style" makes it evident that ro is being joined to ri before ri has been brought in (just replaying your from and where clause) 

<code start>
 from Inventory I
 join RecsOut ro on ro.recsIn_id=ri.id 
 --  ???  join RecsIn ri, --- ??  
 join calc c on c.rawmat_id=i.id 
 joinservrecs sr on sr.serv_id=c.serv_id
 join serv s on s.id=c.serv_id
 join Docs d on d.doc_id= ro.doc_id and d.doc_id=sr.doc_id and d.doc_id=323 
 join unit u on i.unit_k=u.unit_k

</code end>

Comment: @irnerd thank you very much. You advice was very helpful for me. I changed sql code with "new-style join syntax" and easily find out my error. :)

Comment: @irnerd if I add ro.recsin_id=rs.id clause than sql returns only 1 record with id=11446.  I can't explain why!

Comment: @basti - this is where left joins will start to be useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230374/discussion-between-irnerd-and-basti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@basti A major benefit of the "New Style Join" is that each table can be brought in one at a time during development and testing. With each table "joined" it is very straightforward to see which relationship has generated more (or indeed less) records than you are expecting

Translating your code shows me there could be breakage somewhere .  Thanks for replying to comment ...

```
from Inventory I
  join RecsOut ro on ro.recsIn_id=ri.id 
 -- ??? join RecsIn ri, --- ?? 
  join calc c on c.rawmat_id=i.id
  join servrecs sr on sr.serv_id=c.serv_id 
  join serv s on s.id=c.serv_id 
  join Docs d on d.doc_id= ro.doc_id 
      and d.doc_id=sr.doc_id
      and d.doc_id=323 
  join unit u on i.unit_k=u.unit_k
```

Don't forget to embrace inner , left and outer joins